# Pycharm Python Crashing

Tags: python, pycharm

Python crashes a lot in the latest version of PyCharm on Windows 8.  Does anyone have a fix?

```
Here is the Python build info.

PyCharm 3.1.2
Build #PY-133.1229, built on April 3, 2014
JRE: 1.70_40-b43 x86

Operating System:
Windows 8.1 64bit

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    527fcf56
  Fault Module Name:    libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   525049a5
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 000148fe
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.101
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: f671
  Additional Information 2: f6712c9f304c9c2fa68234125a0d4d09
  Additional Information 3: 3d86
  Additional Information 4: 3d8696a5f76d8ed3760b242e408c56fb
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Originally posted as a comment.

The problem was the Flask-Misaka plugin. I compiled the c extension with a different compiler than what python usese. For some reason Python really hates that. I used a different module that doesn't require the extensions and everything works fine now.

Comment: could you please explain how you solved the problem in more details? I am having the same problem in Windows 10, and it is horrendously annoying. But i don't understand how to do the 'compiled the c extension with a different compiler than what python usese'. Thanks alot